# How to open view as popup from poup in asp.net mvc4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, telerik

I've developed an application where I've main view(A.cshtml), in that view I've partial view(B.cshtml) there is telerik mvc grid which has some data. When i click on particular image inside grid, it opens popup which is again a particular view(C.cshtml) which has partial view on it(D.cshtml). In that partial view, I've telerik MVC grid which has some data. When I'll click on that image, I wanna open one more popup with particular view. 
**Please see steps to get question in better manner :**

1. A.cshtml(View)
2. B.cshtml(Partial view in A.cshtml)
3. Telerik MVC grid(In B.cshtml)
4. Image binded as col data(In telerik mvc grid)

**On click event of the image:**

1. Open view as popup(C.cshtml)
2. D.cshtml(Partial view in C.cshtml)
3. Telerik MVC grid(In D.cshtml)
4. Image binded as col data(In telerik mvc grid)

**On click event of the image:**
I want to open more view as popup.

Answer (score 0):

Have a div in A.cshtml. On Image click in B.cshtml make ajax call to return C.cshmtl and set div html content to returned c.cshtml and use jquery ui dialog to show div as popup.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Actually, i resolved that in lil another way. But, could you please elaborate with the some code(Ajax call based code to open url of view)? that will more help me.